# Writing to file with cython.parallel.parallel and nogil

Tags: python, parallel-processing, cython

I'm getting my feet wet with Cython.  Consider me a total noob with it.  Writing to a very large file is a major bottleneck in my code, so I thought I'd look into parallelism, but I haven't been able to find anything useful on writing files with parallelism.

Is it even possible to use a

```
with nogil, parallel():
```

statement with writing to a file?  I get compilation errors when trying to write a string:

```
Constructing Python tuple not allowed without gil
```

Comment: You can't use any Python functions or objects within a nogil block.  If you want to do file IO with nogil, you'll have to do it with C.  This blog post can probably help you: http://www.code-corner.de/?p=183

Comment: @jcrudy : you should post that as an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't use any Python functions or objects within a nogil block. If you want to do file IO with nogil, you'll have to do it with C. This [blog post](http://code-corner.de/?p=183) can probably help you.  Specifically, you can cimport the usual C functions from stdio.  These functions should be usable within nogil blocks.  The below is from the blog post to which I linked above:

```
from libc.stdio cimport *

cdef extern from "stdio.h":
    FILE *fopen(const char *, const char *)
    int fclose(FILE *)
    ssize_t getline(char **, size_t *, FILE *)
```